# How to import a whole different HTML file into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an HTML doc that I want to be loaded into my iframe and then the print preview to pop up on google chrome. This is what I have done so far but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
...
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#printerButton').click(function(){
            openPrintDialogue();
        });
    });
    function openPrintDialogue(){
        $('<iframe>', {
            id: 'frame',
            scr: 'path/to/my/external/html/file',
            name: 'myiframe',
            class: 'printFrame'
        })
          .appendTo('body');

          window.frames['myiframe'].focus();
          window.frames['myiframe'].print();

          setTimeout(() => { $(".printFrame").remove(); }, 1000);
    };
...
</script>
<html>
...
<input type="button" id="printerButton" name="print" value="Print It" />
...
</html>
```

The iframe pops-up but it is just blank and I want it to be populated/filed with the content in the external html file of mine.

NOTE: The main reason I am doing this is because I want to print the external html file on button click. If you know any way that is easier than what I am doing to do that then please inform me.

Thank you.

UPDATE: Solved. Thanks perfect5th!

Comment: Looks like you have a typo. I think `scr` should be `src`.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already told you - "scr" should be "src", but you have another problem:

```
 setTimeout(() => { $(".printFrame").remove(); }, 1000);
```

will not be called until the print window will be closed. 
This is chrome browser limitation..(print window stops the JS to run in the parent window).

And anyway, I would use the id selector rather the class selector to get the iframe.

```
 setTimeout(() => { $("#frame").remove(); }, 1000);
```